# SAS insert text into email body

Tags: sas

This is the original code.

```
filename outmail email type='text/html'
subject='see this'
from="..."
to="..."
attach=("\...\a.pdf"content_type="application/pdf");

ods _all_ close;
ods listing close;
ods html body=outmail style=minimal; 

title1 'AAA';
title2 'BBB';

proc tabulate data=
...
run;

ods html close;
ods listing;
```

But now I don't want to show a tabulated output in the email body, so I remove this part from the original code.

```
proc tabulate data=
...
run;
```

The problem is I won't have titles in the email any more. It seems I have to put some `proc` in the code to make titles exist in the email. But I don't want to show anything in the email body except

`Hi all,`

`Regards,
Balala`

**Update**

I tried this but no luck.

```
filename outmail email type='text'
    subject="AAAA"
    from="..."
    to="..."
    attach=("\\...\text.pdf" content_type="application/pdf");

data _null_;
    file outmail;
    put 'Hi all,';
    put 'First line';
    put 'Second line ';
    put ' ';
    put 'Regards,';
    put 'Balala';
run;
```

But in the email, it shows `Hi all,First lineSecond line Regards,Balala`.

**Update2**

The 2nd option doesn't work for me. 
1st option doesn't work at first, but when I restart SAS session, it works. But I haven't changed any setting.

And interestingly, I change the type to `text/plain` instead of `text` or `text/html` then everything works fine

Comment: Are you asking how to put text content in the email without the use of titles?

Comment: Yes. `put` doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options there.

**Options 1: HTML tags**

Specify HTML tags in your email if you are doing *`content_type="text/html"`*

Example:

```
filename mailbox email 'me@example.com' subject='test email' content_type="text/html"; 

data _null_;
file mailbox;
put "<body>";
put "<p>Hello,</p>" ;
put "<p>Test email sent <br> Regards,</p>" /
'Automated SAS Code';
put "</body>"; 
RUN;
```

**Options 2 "Backslash" pointer:**

Specify backslash at the end of the line to make the pointer to go over the line. Beware of what Quentin pointed in the comments, you could end up with double lines. Depends on the your SAS platform and email server. Documented here (search for in the document "/"):  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000161869.htm

```
filename mailbox email 'me@example.com' subject='test email'; 

data _null_;
file mailbox;
put "Hello," /;
put "Test email sent. "/; 
put "Regards," /;
put "Automated SAS Code";

RUN;
```

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Is this documented? I find it hard to google such answer.

Comment: @W_ee I don't know if it is documented, but does it not work for you? It works for me. Also, since you are creating an HTML body, you can specify in html code the new lines.

Comment: @W_ee Yes, it is documented, here is the link, go down to the slash http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000161869.htm 
It says "advances the pointer to column one of the new line

Comment: @W_ee interesting.  When I run your original code it works as you expect.  And when I add a backslash, it adds an extra blank line after each line.  Curious when you run your original code, does the log say 6 records were written to the file OUTMAIL or 1 record was written?  If it says 6 records were written, perhaps it's a problem with how your mail client is interpreting the line terminators (CR/LF?).  If it says only 1 record was written, then something weird is happening on SAS side. Also wonder what would happen if you changed to send with type="text/html" or similar.

Comment: Oops, just saw your original code is already sending text/html, so pls ignore that part of my comment.  Still interested in the SAS log record count.

Comment: @Quentin you have a point there. My code suggestion wouldn't work. I will rewrite my answer to show two options.

Comment: Yeah, just realized I was accidentally sending text email too, because I used your code not the OP's by mistake.   When sending simple text messages, then the simple CR/LF work as line breaks.  But when you send text/html then CR/LF is not an HTML line break, so it doesn't start a new line, even with the added slash.  I think your first suggestion of adding html breaks makes sense.

Comment: @VasilijNevlev  Using your first option, if the text contains `&`, it will generate warning messages. It seems it interpret the `&` as to resolve macro variable .

Comment: @W_ee If you don't want to resolve any ampersands, use single quotes instead of double quotes or if you don't want to resolve only some of them, consider masking them with SAS macros such as %NRSTR